# java - How to receive a Json object on a Restful web service?

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey, put

I'm implementing a **RESTful Web Service** on Java, with Jersey library. I want it receives a Json object and then convert it to a Usuario class (pojo) for inserting into a database. Here is the current code

**UsuarioResource.java**

```
package com.tienda.rest.recurso;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.tienda.rest.pojo.Usuario;
import com.tienda.rest.service.UsuarioService;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.FormParam;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

/**
 * REST Web Service
 *
 */
@Path("usuario")
public class UsuarioResource {

    @Context
    private UriInfo context;
    private final UsuarioService service;
    private final Gson json;

    /**
     * Creates a new instance of UsuarioResource
     */
    public UsuarioResource() {
        this.service = new UsuarioService();
        this.json = new Gson();
    }

    /* Other codes */

    @PUT
    @Path("registro")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String registrarUsuario(JsonElement usuario) {
        System.out.println((usuario != null) + usuario.getAsString());
        return usuario.getAsString();
        //Usuario nuevo = this.json.fromJson(usuario, Usuario.class);
        //return this.service.registrarUsuario(nuevo);
    }
}
```

**Usuario.java**

```
package com.tienda.rest.pojo;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

/**
 * Clase que representa un registro de la base de datos, de la tabla
 * {@code usuario}.
 */
public class Usuario implements Serializable {

    private String usuario;
    private String nombre;
    private String apellidos;
    private Date fechaNacimiento;
    private String direccion;
    private String telefono;
    private String clave;

    public Usuario() {
    }

    public Usuario(String usuario) {
        this.usuario = usuario;
    }

    public Usuario(String usuario, String clave) {
        this.usuario = usuario;
        this.clave = clave;
    }

    public Usuario(String usuario, String nombre, String apellidos, Date fechaNacimiento, String direccion, String telefono, String clave) {
        this.usuario = usuario;
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.apellidos = apellidos;
        this.fechaNacimiento = fechaNacimiento;
        this.direccion = direccion;
        this.telefono = telefono;
        this.clave = clave;
    }

    public String getUsuario() {
        return usuario;
    }

    public void setUsuario(String usuario) {
        this.usuario = usuario;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getApellidos() {
        return apellidos;
    }

    public void setApellidos(String apellidos) {
        this.apellidos = apellidos;
    }

    public Date getFechaNacimiento() {
        return fechaNacimiento;
    }

    public void setFechaNacimiento(Date fechaNacimiento) {
        this.fechaNacimiento = fechaNacimiento;
    }

    public String getDireccion() {
        return direccion;
    }

    public void setDireccion(String direccion) {
        this.direccion = direccion;
    }

    public String getTelefono() {
        return telefono;
    }

    public void setTelefono(String telefono) {
        this.telefono = telefono;
    }

    public String getClave() {
        return clave;
    }

    public void setClave(String clave) {
        this.clave = clave;
    }

}
```

By the moment, this code throws an `JsonMappingException`. Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use Gson, jersey will work perfectly with JAXB with MOXy provider (default on Glassfish/Payara).

All you have to do is annotate the pojo fields with the right JAXB annotations, then just use the `Usuario` type itself as a method parameter.

```
@PUT
@Path("registro")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String registrarUsuario(Usuario usuario) {
```

Answer (score 0):

I am definitely not familiar with this library, but I'd assume you'll need to tell it how to map the JSON fields to Java attributes. Maybe some sort of annotations?